# Spring batch Spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-batch

We are using spring batch 2.1.x coupled with spring integration 2.0 for the poller jobs. There are scheduled jobs as well in the mix.The launching of all these poller and scheduled jobs happen by invoking the spring batch api. We have around 60-65 jobs in total. Very frequently in the production environment what we are seeing is the jobs go into "starting" and they do not recover. So once we observe such occurrences we have to keep restarting our servers which contains our spring batch application. The backend of the spring batch datasource is Oracle 11gr2.

Comment: So... how did you fix it? What did you try?

Comment: @aviad We haven't had any concrete solution yet. Though we were able to locate the no. of threads that were getting allocated. The execution-context.xml in spring batch admin manager jar had that configuration. We externalized the property value and we could now configure the no. of threads. However the problem still keeps recurring.